# Linux software for creating HDR images?

Tags: linux, software-rec, images, processing, hdr

Is there any good sofware available for linux for creating HDR images?

Comment: This was also answered over on the sister site at: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3996/21

Comment: I don't think that site existed when I asked the question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For panoramic HDRs and images where your (bracketed) exposures are likely to be jittery,

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)  is IMHO the only way to go.

Although, I tend to tell it to emit HDRs, and then I import the generated HDR into [QtPfsGui](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/) for the final tone-mapping to JPEG, and then do minor touch ups ( Cropping, bordering, basic levels ) with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/).

[QtPfsGui Tutorial](http://garmahis.com/tutorials/hdr-tutorial-free-software/)

There are lots of techniques people use in Gimp and Photoshop alike to *approximate* HDR effects, but they are in my opinion Not HDRs, because they don't permit you to emit 32bit-floating point colour files of the *singular* image that contains the full dynamic range.

Also, some programs such as Raytracers can import HDR Images ( they are notable because they have the .hdr or .exr extension most of the time, any file you create with .jpg is not HDR, its just a tonemapped HDR down to LDR ) and use them as environmental lighting maps, to produce glossy reflections like this

[image]

[Povray NewsGroups Reference](http://news.povray.org/povray.binaries.images/thread/%3Cweb.4a24419ecc220bd569f956610@news.povray.org%3E/)

Answer (score 2):

CinePaint

- http://www.cinepaint.org/
- [Creation of HDR Images in CinePaint](http://www.cinepaint.org/docs/br2hdr/HDR_Tutorial-en.html)

Qtpfsgui

- http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience on this, but you can use the gimp, there are some tutorials online.

http://www.instructables.com/id/HDR-photos-with-the-GIMP/

[image]

Comment: Technically, that's not HDR, that technique skips the HDR phase and goes straight to tonemapping. Images produced from Tonemapping are LDR's. Technically, we don't own screens capable of displaying HDR images, because they're 32bit floats, and we're stuck with 32bit ints, and of that, its only 24bit colour usually.

Comment: Fair enough, as I said I don't have a lot of experience in HDR photography. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Its not your fault, 90% of the people who use the term use it wrongly :)

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) command-line graphics library supports Cineon and DPX files. The ImageMagick offshoot/fork GraphicsMagick, on the other hand, relegates Cineon to "legacy" format status, has a far more complete DPX read/write implementation, supports LogLuv TIFF, and lists OpenEXR on its "to do" list.  (ex :http://www.imagemagick.org/script/examples.php)

[CinePaint](http://www.cinepaint.org/) handles the most: Cineon, DPX, OpenEXR, and LogLuv TIFF.

The [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) can handle Cineon and DPX through plugins (and the Cineon plugin is more recent than the DPX plugin).

[Krita](http://www.koffice.org/krita/) supports OpenEXR natively, and inherits the ability to read Cineon and DPX from its ImageMagick dependency.

HDRIE and HDRShop are both multi-format HDR image editors

[exrtools](http://scanline.ca/exrtools/) supports (surprise!) OpenEXR images, while pfstools supports OpenEXR and RGBE.

Source :http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/50413